# Symfony cache:clear when building a docker container or when running it first time?

Tags: docker, symfony, scripting, composer-php, symfony-3.4

I'm containerizing a symfony-3 application within a docker.

Currently, I am copying a complete `parameters.yml` in function of a build `ARG`, so I can make 3 different builds: `devel`, `pre` and `prod` with 3 different config files.

**I already know that the proper way to go would be** to have a single build, therefore a single compiled image binary, for all the environments, and then pass all the config via ENV vars when launching the container. But I need to go with the config copying by now.

I have this towards the end of my Dockerfile:

```
ARG ENVIRONMENT

# Copy the config file.
COPY config/tighten-violet.parameters.${ENVIRONMENT}.yml /files/tighten-violet/app/config/parameters.yml

# Build the composer part
RUN \
    cd /files/tighten-violet && \
    composer --no-ansi --no-interaction install --no-progress  --no-autoloader --no-scripts && \
    composer --no-ansi --no-interaction dump-autoload --no-dev --optimize --classmap-authoritative --no-scripts && \
    composer --no-ansi --no-interaction run-script --no-dev symfony-scripts && \
    php bin/console cache:clear && \
    php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod && \
    php bin/console assetic:dump --env=prod && \
    :

EXPOSE 80

# Start apache
CMD [ "apachectl", "-D", "FOREGROUND" ]
```

It happens that the "builder" host does not provide connection to the production databases... and I am now surprised that when clearing the cache, I see there's a "real connection" to the database. I thought the cache only had relation to "static code parsing" to compile the autoloader, compile the service-containers and so...

I get this error:

```
Updating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache

 // Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug
 // true

 [OK] Cache for the "dev" environment (debug=true) was successfully cleared.

  [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]
  An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out

  [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out

  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out

cache:clear [--no-warmup] [--no-optional-warmers] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command>

Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the symfony-scripts event terminated with an exception

[...]
```

So it seems that the `symfony-scripts` run the Sensio Bundle that in turn, for any reason, is trying to do a real connection.

## Question

If I want to encapsulate a fully-configured symfony-3 app inside a docker, should I run the scripts at build time? Or should I run them somehow as a part of the entry-point script of a run, that first runs the scripts and after that starts the apache?

Comment: Is your database is in the same container? or in a different container? If yes it's possible that your database is not "ready" to handle connections. Check this repository https://github.com/EnMarche/en-marche.fr/blob/master/Makefile

Comment: The database is set as a backing service (ie: another container, or another host, or a managed service; but always "out of that container"). The thing I pass-in via configuration are the connection details (host+dbname+user+pwd). Indeed: When building the "prod" image, the builder host is in our local office, and the local office does not have direct access to the production database. Instead, when the prod image is run as a container in the production host, that network allows connection to the production DB.

Comment: Ok I understand. Sometime that happens when a Twig Extension try to access database or when a service is directly used as a twig variable, do you have something like this? Could you edit your question with your Twig config

Comment: Possibly the reason for the db connection at cache:clear is that you're using DBAL >=2.5 and have not explicitly set server_version.  This causes doctrine to "guess" the version by connecting to the database. More here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#doctrine-dbal-configuration "If you don’t define this option and you haven’t created your database yet, you may get PDOException errors because Doctrine will try to guess the database server version automatically and none is available.". So don't rely on an ENV var to set the value,  set it in doctrine.yaml.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to split the composer part into 2 separate blocks:

### Block 1 of composer instructions

The part that downloads the packages. This can run inside the "builder".

### Block 2 of composer instructions

The part that uses the downloaded packages to warm-up the system. This can be run inside the running container, which will be run "in place" so taking in account the environment and having access to the proper backing services.

## Implementation

### Dockerfile

This way, I changed the `RUN` command in my Dockerfile from

```
RUN \
    cd /files/tighten-violet && \
    composer --no-ansi --no-interaction install --no-progress  --no-autoloader --no-scripts && \
    composer --no-ansi --no-interaction dump-autoload --no-dev --optimize --classmap-authoritative --no-scripts && \
    composer --no-ansi --no-interaction run-script --no-dev symfony-scripts && \
    php bin/console cache:clear && \
    php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod && \
    php bin/console assetic:dump --env=prod && \
    :
```

into

```
RUN \
    cd /files/tighten-violet && \
    composer --no-ansi --no-interaction install --no-progress  --no-autoloader --no-scripts && \
    :
```

ie: I stripped out everything except for "downloading the packages into /vendor", as "downloading" does not depend on environment variables or configuration.

Up to here, I have a shippable docker image with the `/vendor` already populated.

But still there's one step missing... where do those missing lines go?

### bootstrap.sh

What I did is a bootstrap script so I changed the CMD line from

```
CMD [ "apachectl", "-D", "FOREGROUND" ]
```

into

```
CMD [ "/files/bootstrap.sh" ]
```

The `boostrap.sh` file gets also copied during the build process... and here's the content (simple initial version):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Provision
composer --no-ansi --no-interaction dump-autoload --no-dev --optimize --classmap-authoritative --no-scripts && \
composer --no-ansi --no-interaction run-script --no-dev symfony-scripts
php bin/console cache:clear && \
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod && \
php bin/console assetic:dump --env=prod

# Start the server
apachectl -D FOREGROUND
```

This contains the "installation part" that potentially could depend on the environment, including the dumping of the autoload, the SensioBundle scripts and the caches and dumps. Just in case there are ENV vars that change the behaviour we want to cache.

This happens to work upon `docker run`. But if you do `docker stop` and then `docker start` again, the provisioning part runs also over and over again (stop+start does not freeze the process state, as "pause" does, it kills the process and then restarts it again, starting over from the beginning of the `bootstrap.sh`.

Therefore I could improve the boostrap script so it flags if it has been auto-provisioned. This is the improved (and final) second version of the `bootstrap.sh` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

provisionIfNeeded()
{
    PROVISIONED=/tmp/provisioned
    if [ ! -f ${PROVISIONED} ]; then

        echo "------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
        echo "Provisioning"
        echo "------------------------------------------------------------------------------"

        composer --no-ansi --no-interaction dump-autoload --no-dev --optimize --classmap-authoritative --no-scripts && \
        composer --no-ansi --no-interaction run-script --no-dev symfony-scripts
        php bin/console cache:clear && \
        php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod && \
        php bin/console assetic:dump --env=prod

        echo "------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
        echo "Ended provisioning"
        echo "------------------------------------------------------------------------------"

        touch ${PROVISIONED}
    fi
}

startServer()
{
    echo "Starting httpd."
    exec apachectl -D FOREGROUND

    # If you do all (including provisioning) with an
    # unprivileged user, then do this:
    # exec sudo --preserve-env apachectl -D FOREGROUND
}

provisionIfNeeded
startServer
```

So, upon `docker run`:

1. The script starts, tries to do a provision if needed.
2. It tests the flag.
3. As it is not found, does the provision invoking the missing lines in the Dockerfile.
4. On end of provisioning, flags the container as provisioned.
5. Then it starts the apache.

And upon `docker start`:

1. The script starts, tries to do a provision if needed.
2. The flag is found, so no provision is done.
3. Then it starts the apache.

The 10 seconds of the provisioning are taken away from the build stage and moved into the run stage.

### Cons

Starting the container *for the first time only* lasts about 10 seconds more than if we provisioned during the build stage.

### Pros

The container is perfectly "written" with the caches that belong to each of the run environments, while keeping the build stage via Dockerfile to contain the maximum common factor across all environments.

Hope to help!

Comment: It is better to write "exec apachectl -D FOREGROUND" instead of "apachectl -D FOREGROUND" to better handle signaling.

Comment: True. This has evolved over time. In addition to your exec, I use to set an unprivileged user before the end of the Dockerfile, so when I do `docker exec` I end up being a normal user. This also allows me that the provisioning is done as the unprivileged user. Then I have to run apache as root using `sudo --preserve-env` to send ENV vars from docker straight to apache and then to PHP. I end up doing this: `exec sudo --preserve-env apachectl -D FOREGROUND` - going to edit the answer. Thanks for catching up.

Comment: good job. worth noting that if the user can sudo, the user is as dangerous as root. therefore i prefer running the container as root and let apache switch user himself. And i do this in my bootstrap script : su -l www-data -s /bin/bash -c 'php app/console cache:clear'